# Using Sorl-Thumbnail on url field, not always images

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I have a field that I want to use sorl thumbnail on to convert links to thumbnails. I have set it up and when the link is an image, it shows perfectly well.

But, when the link is not an image, eg just having http://www.google.com, sorl goes through and tries to create a thumbnail, produces a non-existant file name and therefore a broken image link on the front end. How can I get it to create a thumbnail if it is an image, otherwise not create a thumbnail at all?

I thought {% empty %} would work, but that seems to only work if there is NO url at all.

My code:

```
{% thumbnail post.imagelink "600x225" crop="center" as im %}
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-{{ post.id }}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}"></a>
  {% empty %}
  no image
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Comment: There are ways you can overcome this, but that would require checking the url, which creates overhead, maybe the best way would be to separate non image logic from image logic in the fields / model directly, introduce a field that should be used only for images and a separate for non image references

Comment: Fair point. I am taking this from a user input field - so it is intended to be images only, but I am trying to cater for if it isn't. Unless there is some way to check if a url is an image in the form?